# How to get unsubscriber data in Service cloud using Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, unsubscribe

We are using Salesforce object as the entry criteria for a journey in Marketing Cloud. We need to update a custom field on Service cloud if the email receiver unsubscribes.
Whats the best approach to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** 
If you are using a custom profile center, you can use `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` to update your custom field once the contact is on your landing page.

```
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Contact',@ContactId,'YourCustomField_HasOptedOut','true')
```

**PS:** if you go with this option, keep in mind that some contacts that complaint about your email ,by clicking the 'report spam' on their inbox, get automatically unsubscribed from Marketing Cloud. You need to unsubscribe them as well on your custom field since they did not go through your profile center and therfore not covered by the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject updates on Service Cloud.

**Option 2:** 
Or, you can implement this process on Service cloud using a Process Builder. Basically, it will update your custom field every time the standard consent field is updated.

I believe there are other options. Let me know if you need more explanation..

Comment: Thank you @Rachid Mamai